# Spark : How to set deploy mode on code?

Tags: apache-spark

I know that cluster mode can be set up at spark-submit script. But I want to set up on application by code or executable options such as java -Dspark.submit.deploymode=cluster ~~.

I want to run my spark app on cluster mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the spark-submit command, and you want to launch a Spark job using your own Java code then you will need to use the Spark Java APIs, mainly the org.apache.spark.launcher package:
[Spark 1.6 Java API Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html)

The code below was taken from the link and slightly modified.

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkAppHandle;
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

public class MyLauncher {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   SparkAppHandle handle = new SparkLauncher()
     .setAppResource("/my/app.jar")
     .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
     .setMaster("XXX") // Master URL based on doc in [2]
     .setDeployMode("cluster")
     .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
     .startApplication();
   // Use handle API to monitor / control application.
 }
}
```